# Get list of existing sessions on connect-redis

Tags: node.js, session, express, node-redis

I have to implement a feature that if logged users count exceeds allowed number of users then no more users should be allowed to login. Is there a way to get the list of running/existing sessions? and how to destroy a specific session? Can anyone provide an example as i am new in node. Part of my code is:

```
express = require('express'),
session = require('express-session'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

redisOpts = {
    pass: config.REDIS_PASS,
    host: config.REDIS_SERVER || null,
    port: config.REDIS_PORT || null
},

sessionStore = new RedisStore(redisOpts),

app = express();

app.use(session({
   store: sessionStore,
   secret: 'XXX',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

**Edit**

```
express = require('express'),
session = require('express-session'),
redis   = require("redis"),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

redisOpts = {
    pass: config.REDIS_PASS,
    host: config.REDIS_SERVER || null,
    port: config.REDIS_PORT || null
},

redisClient = redis.createClient(redisOpts.port, redisOpts.host, { auth_pass: redisOpts.pass }),
sessionStore = new RedisStore(redisClient),
app = express();

app.use(session({
   store: sessionStore,
   secret: 'XXX',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

and in app.js inside login function if check for list of session:

```
redisClient.keys("sess:*", function(error, keys){
        console.log("Number of active sessions: ", keys.length);
        console.log(keys);
});
```

after this edit, its throwing an error in connect-redis.js on this line :

```
 TypeError: this.client.unref is not a function
 if (options.unref) this.client.unref();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to query the redis collection directly though.

Since connect-redis uses `redis.createClient()` internally, you can pass an instance of the redis client in instead of credentials.  Something like:

```
//I've kept your redisOpts for clarity
redisOpts = {
    pass: config.REDIS_PASS,
    host: config.REDIS_SERVER || null,
    port: config.REDIS_PORT || null
},

var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisOpts.port, redisOpts.host, { auth_pass: redisOpts.pass });
```

Now, configure your redis store as before, but pass in the redisClient

```
sessionStore = new RedisStore(redisClient)
```

You can now use the same `redisClient` to query number of session keys

```
redisClient.keys("sess:*", function(error, keys){
    console.log("Number of active sessions: ", keys.length);
});
```

Comment: This is giving an error: 
TypeError: this.client.unref is not a function
on this line -> if (options.unref) this.client.unref(); in connect-redis.js

Comment: where abouts does that throw?

Comment: when i restart my node, on this line https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js#L89

Comment: hmm that's weird, that's the library throwing the error..... can you edit your question to show your new code, passing in the redisClient to `RedisStore`

Comment: hmm, what version of redis client have you installed? did you install via npm?

Comment: try changing the creation of the redisClient to `var redisClient = redis.createClient({port: redisOpts.port, host: redisOpts.host, auth_pass: redisOpts.pass, unref: false});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96019/discussion-between-arsinawaz-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

I usually set a name for each session like:

```js
var redis_client = redis.createClient();
redis_client.client('setname', 'tour-client');
```

And then when I want to check for it:

```js
redis_client.multi().client(['list']).exec(function(err, results) {
  var pairs = results[0].split(' ');
  pairs.forEach(function(pair){
    var kv = pair.split('=');
    if (kv[0] == 'name' && kv[1] == 'some-name-looking-for')
      found = true;
  });
  if (found) {
    // some logic
  }
});
```